# Range of $\operatorname{arcsec}(\sec x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I know, this is very simple question, but sometimes I get stuck on simple questions!

Let denote, range of function $f(x)$ by $R(f(x))$, then ,

How, $\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\sec\dfrac \pi 2\right)= \dfrac \pi 2$ ?

I mean, 
How $\dfrac \pi 2 \in R(\operatorname{arcsec}(\sec x))$ ?

Since, $\sec x$ is not defined at $x = \dfrac \pi 2$. so how can be $\operatorname{arcsec}(\sec x)$ can be defined at $x = \dfrac \pi 2$ ?

I think, $R(\operatorname{arcsec}(\sec x)) = [0, \pi] -\left\{\dfrac \pi 2\right\}$. But it is not true. How?

Comment: MathJax hint: if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sec x gives $\sec x$ as opposed to sec x which gives $sec x$  It doesn't work for arcsec, though.  For that you need \operatorname {arcsec}

Comment: For the implicit assumption that our variables range over the real numbers, you are right; $\pi/2$ is no good.  For the alternative assumption that our variables range over the Riemann sphere, then you are not right.  From our remarks we may guess that Wolfram Alpha is using that convention.

Comment: @GEdgar, no Wolfram is not assuming that, because it shows $x ∈ R$

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is spot on.  The [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\operatorname {arcsec} (x)$ does not include $\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: But wolfarm alpha, and my textbook says, range of $arcsec(secx)$ includes $π/2$

Comment: By the way, your answer is for, arcsec(x) but my question is for arcsec(secx). Please read the question.

Comment: I did read the question.  The range of $\operatorname{arcsec}(\sec(x))$ is always a subset of the range of $\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$, so if $\frac \pi 2$ is missing from the latter it is missing from the former.

Comment: Thank u so much sir. But then what you tell me for my first comment. How wolfarm alpha is wrong.

Comment: Sir, wolfarm didn't give me range of above function. But when I search, arcsec(sec π/2)) then wolfarm alpha shows its value equal to π/2.

Comment: Alpha is often wrong in corner cases like this.  It tends to assume things are generic, so it has a rule that $\operatorname {arcsec}(\sec(x))=x \pmod \pi$ and doesn't worry about the $\frac \pi 2$ case.

Comment: Thank u so much. Now it's clear..:-)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it's not defined at that point.

We can say $$f(x) = g(h(x))$$ for $h(x) = sec(x) $ and $g(x) = arcsec(x)$
.

Since $h(x)$ is undefined at $x=\frac \pi2$, the domain AND range for $g(x)$ is undefined at $h(\frac \pi2)$.